# import jaudiotagger to eclipse

Tags: java

I'm working on a program which loads the song data of a mp3 file. Im trying to import JAudioTagger to help load the song information. The JAudioTagger is a .jar file. I'm not sure if any of these options are the correct ones.

Does anyone know about how to import the jar file to eclipse? I am using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to import the jar file? Or you just want to add it to classpath of your project?

Answer (score 1):

write click on your project select the `buildpath -->select the libraries-->add external jars-->select jar from your system`...